# Use environment variables in wildlfy datasource definition (file)

Tags: docker, jboss, environment-variables, wildfly, datasource

I want to repackage my WAR application as self containing docker-image - currently still deploying as `war` to wildfly 19.
Since I don´t want to have the database password and/or URL be part of the docker image I want it to be configurable from outside - as environment variable.

So my current docker image includes a wildfly datasource definition as `-ds.xml` file  with `env` placeholders since according to

- https://blog.imixs.org/2017/03/17/use-environment-variables-wildfly-docker-container/

and other sources this should be possible.

My DS file is

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/dbtDS" pool-name="benchmarkDS">
        <driver>dbt-datasource.ear_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1</driver>
        <connection-url>${DB_CONNECTION_URL,env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</connection-url>
        <security>
            <user-name>${DB_USERNAME,env.DB_USERNAME}</user-name>
            <password>${DB_PASSWORD,env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
        </security>

        <pool>[...]</pool>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

But starting the docker container leads always to not recognizing the environment variables:

```
11:00:38,790 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:jboss/datasources/dbtDS: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
       [...]
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031083: Wrong driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] for this connection URL []
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:323)
```

last line says, that `DS_CONNECTION_URL` seems to be empty - tried several combinations - believe me.

```
Wrong driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] for this connection URL []
```

I´m starting my container with

```
docker run --name="dbt" --rm -it -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990     -e DB_CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:13306/dbt?serverTimezone=UTC"     -e DB_USERNAME="dbt"     -e DB_PASSWORD="_dbt" dbt
```

I even modified the `standalone.sh` to output environments and `DB_CONNECTION_URL` *IS* there.

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  DB_CONNECTION_URL: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:13306/dbt?serverTimezone=UTC     JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

11:00:34,362 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.1.Final
11:00:34,854 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.11.Final
11:00:34,863 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
[...]
```

So what am I doing wrong to enable wildfly to replace placeholders in my DS file??
They seem to be processed - since they evaluate to empty. But they should contain something...

Any suggestions appreciated.

Current Dockerfile

```
[...] building step above [...]

FROM jboss/wildfly:20.0.1.Final
USER root
RUN yum -y install zip wget && yum clean all

RUN sed -i 's/echo "  JAVA_OPTS/echo "  DB_CONNECTION_URL: $DB_CONNECTION_URL     JAVA_OPTS/g' /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh && \
    cat /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh
RUN sed -i 's/<spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false<\/spec-descriptor-property-replacement>/<spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true<\/spec-descriptor-property-replacement><jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true<\/jboss-descriptor-property-replacement><annotation-property-replacement>true<\/annotation-property-replacement>/g' /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml


USER jboss
COPY --from=0 /_build/dbt-datasource.ear /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
ADD target/dbt.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

Answer (score 1):

Answere to myself - perhaps good to know for others later:

Placeholder in `-ds.xml` files are NOT supported(!).

I added the same `datasource` definition in the `standalone.xml` by patching with `sed` and now it works without further modification more or less out of the box.

Comment: As I am reluctant to sed-edit standalone.xml I'd prefer using jboss-cli commands but failed in a Kubernetes environment. Do you have experience how to use jboss-cli to add a datasource based on variables?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It took me a while but I found that I needed to add a

```
reload
```

command in the config.d script so that my properties volume would be picked up for my datasource xml.

Actually the above still doesn't work.

This worked though:
Found out that I needed to mount my properties file in a different location so as to not conflict with an existing wildfly volume.